# On variable naming as part of Unit tests

Tags: naming-conventions

At this moment, i am writing tests to handle comparisons between different KVPair classes, where content differs by the amount of white space in either KVPair.

I am constructing objects as follows:

```
k = "remember";
v = "It's not a lie, if you believe it";
remember_SingleSpaceOnTargetNoSpaceOnSource = new KVPair(k, v); // notice var name
...
```

This quickly broke down when i had to create more complex tests.

**How would you name a variable, key characteristic of which is `space2Tabs3SpacesContent` and still have an idea what this means a month from now?**

Ultimately  as part of my tests, i need to cover cases of:

```
{various spaces} content {various spaces}
content {various spaces}
{various spaces} content
```

Any suggestions on how to best structure this for ease of testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this variable is local (used inside single sub or function), I would use comments, since it is really hard to put all the meaning into the name.
For example

```
// this var stores something .../indicates something .../just for lulz here :)
var space2Tabs3SpacesContent
```

Using comments is the best way to remember something in two months ;)